# The loss remains constant everytime I run the caffe model on the dataset

Tags: image-processing, deep-learning, caffe, lmdb

The initial loss which is computed when my model is run on the image dataset is remaining constant everytime I run caffe. Isn't the behavior strange , since the initial loss should be different (atleast slightly) when we run the model every-time.

Also the loss value is remaining constant across the further iterations if I give SoftmaxWithLoss function in the loss layer. Also, if I give lr_mult=0 in the deconvolution layer, the loss is appearing constant across iterations. If I give  lr_mult=1, then the loss value changes , but finally will meet the intial loss value after few thousand iterations.

Any ideas in this regard?

Any help is highly appreciated in this regard.

The following is my solver file:

```
test_iter: 100
test_interval: 100 # py solving tests
display: 100
#average_loss: 100
lr_policy: "fixed"
base_lr: 0.0000001
momentum: 0.5
iter_size: 1
# base_lr: 1e-9
# momentum: 0.99
# iter_size: 1
max_iter: 1000000
#weight_decay: 0.0005
snapshot: 1000
snapshot_diff: true 
#test_initialization: false
solver_mode: GPU
```

The following is the architecture of my convolutional neural network.

```
# Input 128 640 3
# Conv1 (kernel=3) 126 638 64
# ReLU
# Conv2 (kernel=3) 124 636 128
# ReLU
# Conv3 (kernel=3) 122 634 256
# ReLU
# Pool1 (kernel=2) 61 317 256
# Conv4 (kernel=4) 58 314 512
# ReLU
# Conv5 (kernel=4) 55 311 1024
# ReLU
# Conv6 (kernel=4) 52 308 512
# ReLU
# Pool2 (kernel=2) 26 154 512
# Conv7 (kernel=4,stride=2,pad=3) 15 79 5
# ReLU
# Decon1 (kernel=16,stride=8,pad=3) 128 640 5
# ReLU
# Loss

name: "Conv-Deconv-Net"
layer {
  name: "data"
  type: "Data"
  top: "data"
  include {
    phase: TRAIN
  }
  data_param {
    source: "F:/shripati/v9/Models/3_Conv_Deconv_Arch_SoftmaxWithLoss/Data/training_lmdb_files/training_files_orig_IMG_LMDB_olpywm"
    batch_size: 4
    backend: LMDB
  }
}
layer {
  name: "label"
  type: "Data"
  top: "label"
  include {
    phase: TRAIN
  }
  data_param {
    source: "F:/shripati/v9/Models/3_Conv_Deconv_Arch_SoftmaxWithLoss/Data/training_lmdb_files/training_files_orig_LBL_LMDB_olpywm"
    batch_size: 4
    backend: LMDB
  }
}
layer {
  name: "data"
  type: "Data"
  top: "data"
  include {
    phase: TEST
  }
  data_param {
    source: "F:/shripati/v9/Models/3_Conv_Deconv_Arch_SoftmaxWithLoss/Data/testing_lmdb_files/testing_files_IMG_LMDB_olpywm"
    batch_size: 4
    backend: LMDB
  }
}
layer {
  name: "label"
  type: "Data"
  top: "label"
  include {
    phase: TEST
  }
  data_param {
    source: "F:/shripati/v9/Models/3_Conv_Deconv_Arch_SoftmaxWithLoss/Data/testing_lmdb_files/testing_files_LBL_LMDB_olpywm"
    batch_size: 4
    backend: LMDB
  }
}
layer {
  name: "conv1"
  type: "Convolution"
  bottom: "data"
  top: "conv1"
  param {
    lr_mult: 1
    decay_mult: 1
  }
  param {
    lr_mult: 2
    decay_mult: 0
  }
  convolution_param {
    num_output: 64
    kernel_size: 3
    stride: 1
    pad: 0
    weight_filler {
      type: "xavier"
    }
    bias_filler {
      type: "constant"
    }
  }
}
layer {
  name: "relu1"
  type: "ReLU"
  bottom: "conv1"
  top: "relu1"
}
layer {
  name: "conv2"
  type: "Convolution"
  bottom: "relu1"
  top: "conv2"
  param {
    lr_mult: 1
    decay_mult: 1
  }
  param {
    lr_mult: 2
    decay_mult: 0
  }
  convolution_param {
    num_output: 128
    pad: 0
    kernel_size: 3
    weight_filler {
      type: "xavier"
    }
    bias_filler {
      type: "constant"
      value: 0
    }
  }
}
layer {
  name: "relu2"
  type: "ReLU"
  bottom: "conv2"
  top: "relu2"
}
layer {
  name: "conv3"
  type: "Convolution"
  bottom: "relu2"
  top: "conv3"
  param {
    lr_mult: 1
    decay_mult: 1
  }
  param {
    lr_mult: 2
    decay_mult: 0
  }
  convolution_param {
    num_output: 128
    pad: 0
    kernel_size: 3
    stride: 1
    weight_filler {
      type: "xavier"
    }
    bias_filler {
      type: "constant"
      value: 0.001
    }
  }
}
layer {
  name: "relu3"
  type: "ReLU"
  bottom: "conv3"
  top: "relu3"
}
layer {
  name: "pool1"
  type: "Pooling"
  bottom: "relu3"
  top: "pool1"
  pooling_param {
    pool: MAX
    kernel_size: 2
    stride: 2
  }
}

layer {
  name: "conv4"
  type: "Convolution"
  bottom: "pool1"
  top: "conv4"
  param {
    lr_mult: 1
    decay_mult: 1
  }
  param {
    lr_mult: 2
    decay_mult: 0
  }
  convolution_param {
    num_output: 128
    pad: 0
    kernel_size: 4
    stride: 1
    weight_filler {
      type: "xavier"
    }
    bias_filler {
      type: "constant"
      value: 0.001
    }
  }
}
layer {
  name: "relu4"
  type: "ReLU"
  bottom: "conv4"
  top: "relu4"
}

layer {
  name: "conv5"
  type: "Convolution"
  bottom: "relu4"
  top: "conv5"
  param {
    lr_mult: 1
    decay_mult: 1
  }
  param {
    lr_mult: 2
    decay_mult: 0
  }
  convolution_param {
    num_output: 256
    pad: 0
    kernel_size: 4
    stride: 1
    weight_filler {
      type: "xavier"
    }
    bias_filler {
      type: "constant"
      value: 0.001
    }
  }
}
layer {
  name: "relu5"
  type: "ReLU"
  bottom: "conv5"
  top: "relu5"
}

layer {
  name: "conv6"
  type: "Convolution"
  bottom: "relu5"
  top: "conv6"
  param {
    lr_mult: 1
    decay_mult: 1
  }
  param {
    lr_mult: 2
    decay_mult: 0
  }
  convolution_param {
    num_output: 128
    pad: 0
    kernel_size: 4
    stride: 1
    weight_filler {
      type: "xavier"
    }
    bias_filler {
      type: "constant"
      value: 0.001
    }
  }
}
layer {
  name: "relu6"
  type: "ReLU"
  bottom: "conv6"
  top: "relu6"
}

layer {
  name: "pool2"
  type: "Pooling"
  bottom: "relu6"
  top: "pool2"
  pooling_param {
    pool: MAX
    kernel_size: 2
    stride: 2
  }
}

layer {
  name: "conv7"
  type: "Convolution"
  bottom: "pool2"
  top: "conv7"
  param {
    lr_mult: 1
    decay_mult: 1
  }
  param {
    lr_mult: 2
    decay_mult: 0
  }
  convolution_param {
    num_output: 5
    pad: 3
    kernel_size: 4
    stride: 2
    weight_filler {
      type: "xavier"
    }
    bias_filler {
      type: "constant"
      value: 0.001
    }
  }
}
layer {
  name: "relu7"
  type: "ReLU"
  bottom: "conv7"
  top: "relu7"
}


layer {
  name: "deconv1"
  type: "Deconvolution"
  bottom: "relu7"
  top: "deconv1"
  param {
    lr_mult: 1
  }
  convolution_param {
    num_output: 5
    bias_term: false
    kernel_size: 16
    stride: 8
    pad: 0
    weight_filler {
      type: "bilinear"
    }
  }
}
layer {
  name: "relu8"
  type: "ReLU"
  bottom: "deconv1"
  top: "relu8"
}


#layer {
#  name: "crop"
#  type: "Crop"
#  bottom: "deconv3"
#  bottom: "data"
#  top: "score"
#}
layer {
  name: "prob"
  type: "SoftmaxWithLoss"
  bottom: "relu8"
  bottom: "label"
  top: "loss"
  loss_param {
    # ignore_label: 255
    # normalize: true
    normalize: false
  }
}
```

Comment: What is your learning rate?

Comment: Hi, I added the solver and config file in the edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems your `base_lr` is too small. Keep it at `0.00001` in the beginning and try keeping your `momentum` at `0.9`. If your learning rate is too small, convergence will be very slow and if it is too high gradient descent will overshoot the local minima (that's when you see your loss shoots up). So you have to come at an optimal value, iteratively. There is no magic number for this.

Comment: I tried with 0.001 but problem is the loss just shoots up to 7.51e6 in first few iterations.

Comment: I ran around 4k iterations initially.

Comment: I had ran it once yesterday, but after completion of iterations , the value of loss had returned to the initial value of loss. There were wild fluctuations to some point in the iterations, but after some time the value of loss remained constant.